# Im ready for grouting what to use?

Tags: tile, grout, support

I'm almost ready to grout.

1. What unsanded grout should I use?
   Is it ok to any if the ones in the picture? The tube will be easier for me.
2. Do I need to use a sealer after?
3. After tiling using the leveling spacers system few where stuck in between that I cant reach to pull (close to the tile surface but no edge to pull), is it ok to leave them when grouting or u should find a  way to remove them.
4. Just a question wondering, why not using silicon caulk instead of the grout since its water proof.
5. What color should I use with tile (is white ok?)

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Grout goes between the tiles.  Caulk goes in the corners at changes in planes.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you use sanded grout for seams over 1/8" and non-sanded for under. Any good quality grout will do the trick if you follow the on-package instructions. Regarding the spacers, you want to remove them mainly because they'll cause a gap or weak point in the seam that could cause the grout to fail prematurely. Try using an awl or small screwdriver to get under the spacers and pry them out.
That silicone caulk will be fine for corners and along tub edges, etc.and should come in varying colors but silicone, while waterproof, is difficult to work with. You may think it will be easier to use but it isn't - it's meant for small patch jobs and edge seams. I'd stick with the grout which is very simple and easy to use. Again just follow the directions and **yes** you will want to seal it afterwards. Grout isn't waterproof and only marginally water-resistant.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer very helpuful..the caulk tube in the picture is Non sanded grout ,cant I use it for grouting as it will be easier for me to fill the gaps and use?

Comment: Chad - You can try to use it for whatever you want but I would discourage it. Read the label. The front of the tube in the picture tells you, "Use around tubs and sinks", use where horizontal and vertical surfaces meet. It's only meant for specific types of applications. I know it also says "Siliconized for ease of use" but believe me silicone is very tacky and and hard to work with. The other issue is that caulk, even silicone caulk, will not have the longevity of grout. How large is the area you are tiling? Is it a floor or wall?

Comment: The bottom line here is that it's not meant to do what you want it to do. It's not grout, it's caulk.

Comment: Oh ok..I was confused because I read the Grout in purple.and also i dont know what's the difference between caulk and silicone (i thought the are the same)..thanks for the clarification.area size of the walls is 60sqf its bathtub walls .

Comment: Chad grout is pushed into the seams with a float,  you need to research this before you attempt it. do a YouTube search of how to grout a bathtub surround to learn the proper way to grout

Comment: Alaska Man is right. YouTube is a good place to learn how to grout. Once you know how to do it it's a simple, easy process. With all of the work you've put in to this point don't try to shortcut it at the finish. Sealing is easy as well. You can also see that on YouTube.

Comment: Even though this is a wall remove the spacers use needle nose pliers or at least cut them with a razor they should not be under the tiles anything in the spaces weakens the grout. In a shower I always seal after the grout has had time to cure. As far as sanded non sanded I use sanded on floors non sanded on counters and walls.  Last thanks are nice but upvote helpful comments or answers if you use the answer accept it . There is a lot of good comments that support this answer. +++ last grout in corners can crack so the silicone or epoxy grout are better options in corners.